# Setting a new items' DropLink field value using PowerShell

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have set a value in a `General link` field in a Sitecore item using PowerShell. Here is the PowerShell script.

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()                        

[Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$fieldValueLink = $Item.Fields[$templateField.DisplayName]

$fieldValueLink.Text = "Link"
$fieldValueLink.Title = "click on the link"
$fieldValueLink.LinkType = "external"
$fieldValueLink.Url = $itemRow.$fieldTrimmedValue

$item[$templateField.DisplayName] = $fieldValueLink.Value;

$item.Editing.EndEdit() | Out-Null
```

Now I want to set values into other field types like `DropLink`, `Multilist` and `DropList`. For setting these field values I think I need to create Sitecore items using PowerShell and then assign them to the fields' values, But I don't know where to start and how to proceed.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

To create a new item with Sitecore Powershell Extensions, use `New-Item`:

```
$newItemParentPath = "/sitecore/content/Home"
$newItemTemplate = "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}"

$newItem = New-Item -Path $newItemParentPath -Name "New Item Name" -ItemType $newItemTemplate
```

Now to assign that new item in `Droplink` field you need to assign ID of that item to the field like:

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item["Droplink field name"] = $newItem.ID
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

and to assign that new item in `Droplist` field you need to assign `Name` of that item to the field like:

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item["Droplist field name"] = $newItem.Name
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

Comment: If i want to add a **datasource** which has more items then, should i need to add give value for sort. Or please tell me how to add list of items to a droplink field.

Comment: I'm trying something like this.                                                    
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
 $allItems = Get-ChildItem -Path '/sitecore/content/ListManagerTask' -Recurse
                        foreach($droplinkItem in $allItems){
                            
                         $item[$templateField.DisplayName] = $droplinkItem.ID;
                        }
                        
                         $item.Editing.EndEdit() | Out-Null

Comment: So you take some item (`$item`) and then you iterate after `ListManagerTask` and all its descendants and in every loop you assign ID of that descendant to the same field. So after your loop is done, it will be the **last** descendant assigned to `$item[$templateField.DisplayName]` field, right? Btw, don't use `DisplayName` here, use `Name` or `ID`.